# bjam - how to always execute shell script before building a target?

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam, b2

My aim is to build a library which includes version information.

I have a script which will update `./version.cpp` **only when the version has actually changed**. This to prevent unnecessary rebuilds.

I have a lib target which globs `*.cpp`, which is inclusive of `version.cpp`.

The problem is that if I run `bjam` I can see it execute the script, and update `version.cpp`, but **the library is not rebuilt.**

Only when I run `bjam` again does it see that `version.cpp` has changed, and rebuild the lib

**My jam file:**

```
Echo [ SHELL "./write_version.sh" ] ;

lib foo
    : [ glob *.cpp ]
    ;
```

**Output of running bjam (twice):**

```
$ bjam
Updating version.cpp

...found 119 targets...

$ bjam
...found 121 targets...
...updating 3 targets...
gcc.compile.c++ ../foo/bin/gcc-4.8/debug/link-static/version.o
gcc.archive ../foo/bin/gcc-4.8/debug/link-static/libfoo.a
...updated 3 targets...
```

**Question:**

How can I get **both** the script and the library build working together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that dependencies are resolved when the `Jamfile` is loaded

ie: in the example `Jamfile`:

```
lib foo
    : [ glob *.cpp ]
    ;
```

the cpp files are `globbed` and `stat'd` when the `Jamfile` is loaded. Any that aren't out of date won't be rebuilt.

After loading the `Jamfile`, `bjam` executes the script which generates the updated `version.cpp`, which is **too late.**

A work around is to execute the shell script in the `Jamroot`. In this way `version.cpp` is updated **before** the `Jamfile` which uses it is loaded. The file is `stat'd`, found to be updated, and `lib foo` rebuilt.

**Jamroot:**

```
Echo [ SHELL "./write_version.sh" ] ;

build-project foo ;
```

**foo Jamfile:**

```
lib foo
    : [ glob *.cpp ]
    ;
```